# ngif not load after i go to another route

Tags: angular, components, angular6

hello i try to read data with angular 6 from firestore (firebase)
and when i open the compenent at first time its load and work well but when i go to another component and back its not load and show me the nodata#

```
<div *ngIf="arr?.length > 0 ;else noData">
  <ul *ngFor="let item of arr" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
  <strong>{{item.displayName}}{{item.email}}</strong></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <ng-template #noData>
  <hr>
  <h5>There are no users to display</h5>
  </ng-template>
  </div>
```

ts component

```
    arr: User[] = [];
  constructor(
     public _data: AuthService,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._data.getUsers().subscribe(
      (user: User[]) => {
      this.arr = user;
      // console.log(this.arr);
      }
      );
  }
}
```

service

```
this.users = this.afs.collection('users').snapshotChanges().map(
    changes => {
    return changes.map(
    a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
    data.uid = a.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
    });
    });


  this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid;
        localStorage.setItem('userID', user.uid);


        return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return Observable.of(null);
      }
    })
);

 getUsers() {
  return this.users;
 }
```

my english is not so good so i try to explain again
when i try at first time open component its load all value and work well when i go to another component and back to my component its dont show anything just
"There are no users to display"
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .share() to your service. This will allow your service to essentially cache the data received from the database and should then eliminate any http requests if the data has not changed.

Service:

```
this.users = this.afs.collection('users').snapshotChanges().map(
    changes => {
      return changes.map(
        a => {
           const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
           data.uid = a.payload.doc.id;
           return data;
    })**.share()**;
});
```

Comment: hi i swith your code with mine and i got this error "Failed to compile.

./src/app/core/auth.service.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (37:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                 data.uid = a.payload.doc.id;
|                 return data;
|             }), Math.pow(.share(), ));
|         });
|         this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap(function (user) {"